# Display info on hover SCSS/CSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, parent, siblings

I'm making a hoverable `ul` that displays a `p` element in another `div`.

As there is no parent selector to be had in pure CSS, I'm stuck and cannot figure out how this is supposed to work.

Fiddle won't work for some reason(for me), so here is a bin:

https://jsbin.com/yohapudimo/edit?html,css,output

My best effort was:

```
#infoDrop > li:hover ~ #aboutPara > p{
  display: inline;
}
```

while trying to target a sibling div

Comment: you will need javascript to do what you want with that markup. `#aboutPata` is not a sibling of the `li`.

Comment: trying to avoid scripting both because of page load and skill set.

Comment: Well then it's not possible with pure CSS and that markup. As you already know in CSS _there is no parent selector_

Comment: Please include all code needed in the question itself. Don't make us go off-site to find important parts like mark up. Your best bet is a [MCVE] in the question it self. Use the `<>` button in the editor to add an interactive snippet.

Comment: downvote? do people get downvotes for linking to a fiddle too???

Comment: I tried to c/p code to this post, but I am not reformatting and tabbing everything out to comply with formatting rules. Thanks though.

Comment: I did not down-vote, but yes, unless you include all the code to produce the problem **in the question itself** you will get down votes. Investigate the Stack Snippets in the question editor. external sites go down disappear etc. Going off site takes time and us away from your question. *You should make it as easy as possible for us to help you.*

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be possible without JS... this is untested though so bear with me -- it also has to be an adjacent element, which I'm not sure is a problem or not for you?

If this doesn't work for you, then I'm afraid you'll need JS.

```css
#myPCont p {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.myCont:hover+#myPCont p {
  display: block;
}

#myPCont {
  background: #333;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myCont">
  <ul class="hoverShowP">
    <li>This is my first list item</li>
    <li>This is my second..</li>
    <li>And this is my third.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="myPCont">
  <p>Heyooo!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm working on this. Will mark as answer once I make it work

Comment: Using this it created triple the markup after getting it completely worked out.., but it worked. One day they'll implement a parent selector...  not gonna hold my breath.

Comment: Tripled the markup? Sounds like a reason to revisit that js option. It would probably be lighter than the extra markup and more scalable. Now you have an excuse to expand into that skill set

Comment: @Ja-oonSolo awesome! can you please accept the answer as correct? Thank you!

Comment: as is, the code doesn't work, but it's a step in the right direction. My `ul` needs to display corresponding content for each `li` instead of the single `myPCont`. The `+` selector ended up a `~`.